# hibernate filter entity with his grandchild attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, filter

i need to filter my entity "A" with an attribute of his grandchild. I can't use "where" clause, i must use hibernate annotation if it's possible.

**My EntityA to filter :**

```
@Entity(name="EntityA")
@Table(name="EntityA")
 public class EntityA implements serializable {

    @oneToOne
    @joinColumn(name="entityb_id")
    EntityB entityB;
    }
```

**entityB**

```
@Entity(name="EntityB")
@Table(name="EntityB")
 public class EntityB implements serializable {

    @oneToMany
    @joinColumn(name="entityB_entityC_id")
    List<entityC> entitiesC;
    }
```

**my grandchild attribute is here**

```
@Entity(name="EntityC")
@Table(name="EntityC")
@FilterDef(name="beginDate" ...)
@Filter(name="beginDate", condition=..)
 public class EntityC implements serializable {

  @Column(name="beginDate") 
   Date begin;
    }
```

I already explore some way to use @FilterJoinTable and @Filter but i don't want loose my time if it's actually not possible.